# Router IP between networks of different classes

Tags: cisco, router, subnet, packet-tracer

I have 2 networks that I want to ping each other, one of the networks uses ***class B 172.16.16.0/19*** and the other network is ***class C 192.168.0.0/26***. Both networks have their own subnets and vlans, and both networks have 1 router, and I'm using a third router between the 2 routers.

Which IP class should I use for the ports of the router where routers connect with each other?

Does it even matter what IP classes I use for those ports?

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 (probably before you were born) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which define CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking doesn't use network classes. Please let them rest in peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just forget the classes. They're dead and buried for 25 years.

Either set up static routes for those subnets, or use a routing protocol across the three routers which takes care of the routing table updates.

You could just as well leave out the third router and link the two routers directly with a link subnet of your choosing. At minimum, e.g. `10.42.0.0/31` would do, providing the link addresses `10.42.0.0` and `10.42.0.1`.

With that, on the first router you'd add the link port IP `10.42.0.0/31` and the static route `172.16.16.0/19` -> `10.42.0.1`. On the second router, this is mirrored with the link port IP `10.42.0.1/31` and the static route `192.168.0.0/26` -> `10.42.0.0/31`.

Of course, `10.0.0.0/8` used to be class A in the networking stone age, so you see classes don't matter one bit.

Comment: i tried this and it worked. thank you very much. the reason i mentioned classes is that basically our instructor has told us to use class b and c as to not waste hosts, since i only have 50 hosts on one network we were instructed to use class c, and 200 hosts on the other network so we had to use class b, since class c with 8 subnets can not cover that many hosts. i understand that this is not how it works anymore but i kinda have to follow his instructions. and this is also the reason i was hesitant to use class A on routers, since it provides too many hosts i won't need to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, network classes are still taught ad nauseam. A short mention would totally suffice imho. A network professional has to know what classes are (or used to be) but doesn't need to use them - and shouldn't.

Comment: @gusgusjon "_told us to use class b and c as to not waste hosts_" The entire reason for CIDR was that network classes waste addresses. CIDR lets you properly size networks for the number of hosts.